# jQuery animate a dynamic value of several variables

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-animate

I have an image sprite with 9 links. Instead of indicating the value of each link, I'm trying to animate in jQuery, after dynamically finding out the value and moving accordingly.

Here's the **markup**:

```
<div class="compass">
    <a class="north" href="#" alt="North">&nbsp;</a>
    <a class="east" href="#" alt="East">&nbsp;</a>
    <a class="south" href="#" alt="South">&nbsp;</a>
    <a class="west" href="#" alt="West">&nbsp;</a>
    <a class="northeast" href="#" alt="North East">&nbsp;</a>
    <a class="southeast" href="#" alt="South East">&nbsp;</a>
    <a class="southwest" href="#" alt="South West" >&nbsp;</a>
    <a class="northwest" href="#" alt="North West">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

And the **jQuery**:

```
var westLeft = +2150;
var westTop = +350;
$(".compass a").click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('class');
    var destinationTop = target + 'Top';
    var destinationLeft = target + 'Left';
    $('.map').animate({
        top: destinationTop,
        left: destinationLeft
    }, 1000, 'swing', function(){
        //we're done!
    });
});
```

So I got destinationTop to dynamically show westTop when I click on the west link, but NOT the actual value of westTop. Same for destinationLeft.

Thank you very much.

Comment: We don't have `southTop` `eastLeft`.. values in CSS. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning

Comment: These are just variables that I've created within jQuery - you can name them whatever you want.

Comment: The point is not variable's _name_, >  variable's _value_...

Comment: I understand that westTop is not a value, but I was reproducing the name of the variable I defined earlier in hope that its value would be used, but that didn't work. That's why I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically doing this:

```
$('.map').animate({
    top: 'eastTop',
    left: 'eastLeft'
}, 1000, 'swing');
```

and **these are not remotely valid values**. If you want to *overwrite* to the existing values:

```
$('.map').animate({
    top: '2150',
    left: '350'
}, 1000, 'swing');
```

If you want to *add* to the existing values:

```
$('.map').animate({
    top: '+=2150',
    left: '+=350'
}, 1000, 'swing');
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties

---

> The problem is, I don't have the values, because it depends on which one of the 9 links the user clicks on, that's why I'm trying to figure out how to write a variable that grabs the value of the animation depending on the link (or the link's class). It's not just about writing in the values manually.

Okay, so you want to use the value in `target` to identify a variable. You *could* do this with `eval()` **(don't)**; slightly less evil is [**bracket notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation). Assume the variables are window-scoped, and not local:

```
$(".compass a").click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('class');
    var destinationTop = window[target + 'Top'];
    var destinationLeft = window[target + 'Left'];
    $('.map').animate({
        top: destinationTop,
        left: destinationLeft
    }, 1000, 'swing', function(){
        //we're done!
    });
});
```

Better, however, to just put the values into a dictionary, and again use bracket notation:

```
var values = {
    westLeft: 2150,
    westTop: 350
};

$(".compass a").click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('class');
    var destinationTop = values[target + 'Top'];
    var destinationLeft = values[target + 'Left'];
    $('.map').animate({
        top: destinationTop,
        left: destinationLeft
    }, 1000, 'swing', function(){
        //we're done!
    });
});
```

Comment: He is doing this `top: 'eastTop'`;

Comment: The problem is, I don't have the values, because it depends on which one of the 9 links the user clicks on, that's why I'm trying to figure out how to write a variable that grabs the value of the animation depending on the link (or the link's class). It's not just about writing in the values manually.

Comment: The end result, for example westTop, IS the correct name of the variable defined earlier, but I want to use the value indicated with the variable.

Comment: @TarekShalaby You are a bit confused about variable's name and variable's value, you should use `css()` method or `data-*` attributes instead.

Comment: @undefined no, I think I can take it from here.

Comment: @MattBall Thanks for the edit. It's not working though. An alert of 'destinationTop' gave the message 'undefinedTop'...

Comment: @MattBall Good solution, shouldn't it be `values[target+'Top']`?

Comment: I think I got it! It should be: var destinationTop = values[target+'Top']; and var destinationLeft = values[target+'Left'] ;

Comment: @TarekShalaby yup sorry, I'm just typing too fast here.

Answer (score 1):

Your values become `eastTop`, `eastLeft`, they do not refer to the variable's name, as they are strings, you can use `data=*` attributes instead, try the following:

```
<div class="compass">
    <a data-top="2150" data-left="350" href="#" alt="North">&nbsp;</a>
    <a data-top="2150" data-left="350" href="#" alt="East">&nbsp;</a>
    <a data-top="2150" data-left="350" href="#" alt="South">&nbsp;</a>
    <a data-top="2150" data-left="350" href="#" alt="West">&nbsp;</a>
    <a class="northeast" href="#" alt="North East">&nbsp;</a>
    <a class="southeast" href="#" alt="South East">&nbsp;</a>
    <a class="southwest" href="#" alt="South West" >&nbsp;</a>
    <a class="northwest" href="#" alt="North West">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

```
$(".compass a").click(function(){
    var destinationTop = $(this).data('top');
    var destinationLeft = $(this).data('left');
    $('.map').animate({
        top: destinationTop,
        left: destinationLeft
    }, 1000, 'swing', function(){
        //we're done!
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I've figured it out, though (see comment above). Wouldn't that be better then using non-standard compliant attributes within the markup?

Comment: @TarekShalaby no, `data-*` attributes are 100% legal HTML5.

Comment: @TarekShalaby You are welcome, Matt's solution is really good, note that `data=*` attributes are valid and standard.